# FFmpeg doesn't recognize correct input height in hstack command

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, ffprobe, video-editing

Having an issue with an `hstack` FFmpeg command that has stumped me.

`input1` and `input2` are both vertical 360x640 videos. I am cropping `input1` to a square, merging it vertically with `input2`, then cropping a vertical strip off each side of the resulting video and horizontally merging these three videos (left strip, middle vertically-stacked video, right strip).

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]crop=360:360:0:140,fps=30[v0],[1:v]fps=30[v1],[v0][v1]vstack=inputs=2[m],[m]crop=101:ih:0:0[l],[m]crop=101:ih:259:0[r],[l][m][r]hstack=inputs=3[v];[0:a][1:a]amix[a] -map [v] -map [a] -preset ultrafast ./stackedOutput.mp4
```

When I run this, I get an error:

```
[Parsed_hstack_6 @ 0x7ff5394482c0] Input 1 height 640 does not match input 0 height 1000. [Parsed_hstack_6 @ 0x7ff5394482c0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_hstack_6
```

(Full FFmpeg output [here](https://pastebin.com/BywjUN97).)

But the height of `[m]` (`Input 1` in `hstack`) is **not** `640`, it's `1000`. I have verified this when the commands are run independently.

Why is FFmpeg not recognizing the correct height of `[m]`? Any help or pointers greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=360:360:0:140,fps=30[v0];[1:v]fps=30[v1];[v0][v1]vstack=inputs=2,split=3[lc][m][rc];[lc]crop=101:ih:0:0[l];[rc]crop=101:ih:259:0[r];[l][m][r]hstack=inputs=3[v];[0:a][1:a]amix[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -preset ultrafast ./stackedOutput.mp4
```

Two problems:

1. Your syntax is incorrect. Filters in the same linear chain are separated by commas, and distinct linear chains of filters are separated by semicolons. See [filtering introduction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction).
2. You can't re-use the output from a filter multiple times. In your command `[m]` was already consumed by the first crop, so it is no longer available for the following crop and hstack. The split filter can be used to make multiple copies of a filter output.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I never knew about the "split" option, and appreciate the clarification about commas vs. semicolons. 